# How to convert JSON to GeoJson JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, maps, geojson

I've got a JSON from a database but now I need to convert it into GeoJson to use it in my map

I found this solution but it shows an undefined array.

```
$.getJSON("./origin/neworigin.json", function(jsonData) {
    var outGeoJson = {}
    outGeoJson['properties'] = jsonData
    outGeoJson['type']= "Feature"
    outGeoJson['geometry']= {"type": "Point", "coordinates":
        [jsonData['latitude'], jsonData['longitude']]}
  
    console.log(outGeoJson)
  });
```

This is an example from myJSON

```
[{"station":"BORJA","institution":"SENCICO","longitude":"-77.0064","latitude":"-12.0855"},
    {"station":"SCARQ","institution":"SENCICO","longitude":"-71.5408","latitude":"-16.385"},
    {"station":"SCAR2","institution":"SENCICO","longitude":"-71.5364","latitude":"-16.3934"},...
```

[in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO0w1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the array is empty or not.

Try change the variable names.

OR

Provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to create a valid GeoJSON form JSON.

1. create GeoJSON.Point array and GeoJSON.FeatureCollection
2. create GeoJSON.MultiPoint object
   Here are code snippets:

```js
const jsonData = [{
    "station": "BORJA",
    "institution": "SENCICO",
    "longitude": "-77.0064",
    "latitude": "-12.0855"
  },
  {
    "station": "SCARQ",
    "institution": "SENCICO",
    "longitude": "-71.5408",
    "latitude": "-16.385"
  },
  {
    "station": "SCAR2",
    "institution": "SENCICO",
    "longitude": "-71.5364",
    "latitude": "-16.3934"
  }
];


// to GeoJSON.Point array
const geoJSONPointArr = jsonData.map(row => {
  return {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [row.longitude, row.latitude]
    },
    "properties": row
  }
});

console.log(geoJSONPointArr);

// to GeoJSON.FeatureCollection
const pointArrFeatureCollection = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": geoJSONPointArr
}

console.log(pointArrFeatureCollection);

// to GeoJSON.MultiPoint
const geoJSONMultiPoint = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPoint",
      "coordinates": jsonData.map(row => [row.longitude, row.latitude])
    },
    "properties": {
      originalData: jsonData
    }
  }

console.log(geoJSONMultiPoint);
```

I would also recommend using the turf library, which is very convenient when working with the GeoJSON format.